How to prevent light from penetrating through the model?
I was designing this model, and when I was rendering I got this:

Light is passing through the model

The light uses 100W, and the world has a scattered volume

The model and the light have no modifiers, the camera has no changes from predetermined,
Project is here: https://drive.proton.me/urls/5FFDT0GBCR#CT9k6jWVnRcs

It's hard to tell what's going on here, if you could [edit] to provide some more screenshots

Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add images of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.
